# How to run wire through corner with lots of studs

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I have a new garage addition that I'm doing the electrical for.  I got to the point of running the wires for the front coach lights and realized a snag.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to run the wire to the hole in the lower right of this picture (hope it's easy to see, just under the horizontal 1x6):

[image]

The tarp is where the garage door will be, so no way going right. I have the huge LVL beam in the way of going up.  I have 3 studs in the way going left (with not really any room to drill a hole) before getting to two more studs in the way around the corner.

I know if I dont finish the garage with drywall I can just run the wire on the inside, but I'd like to plan for the future of possibly closing it all in with drywall.  Would my best bet be to just run a small conduit on the inside corner that would be outside of the drywall in the future?

Hope this all makes sense and is explained well.  Let me know if any further clarification or pictures can help.

Comment: can you still pull off the board (osb) that is covering the outside ?

Comment: Yes, staple it down for now, plan for conduit if finished. Saves time and money now, expandable for the future, and don't drill holes unless you absolutely have to. My opinion, so not an official answer.

Comment: Unless of course you could move it to the right side of the garage door, where you might have more flexibility.

Comment: Unfortunately the siding is already up, but that would have been a great idea had I noticed it before!  Also...I have a light on the right side I'm doing as well and in the exact same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drill it.

Just get a spade bit, you have lots of room in the garage opening if that is a stud in the way just start by drilling through that.  Buy some extensions and self feed spade bits.  Drill from the garage opening to the corner then drill from the other direction.  Now to get from one side to the other get 2 fish tapes and insert them and then spin so they hook together then use a plumbers chain with one conductor of your 14/2 looped and twisted through one of the links then duct tape or ele tape the connections and pull your wire.

Comment: Hmmm. That "stud in the way" might be the stud that trims out the garage door opening, not sure if he'd want to drill through that.   If there is no finished siding yet, perhaps he could drill thru the OSB from the outside thru that conglomeration   of studs next to the door.   Then drill an intersecting hole from the wall on the left. To pull the cables(s), use a shop vac to suck thru a strong string or small rope, attach to the cable(s) and pull them thru.

Comment: There should be a jamb trim that goes over the jamb stud else the wall cladding on both sides will be untidy.  that should cover the hole.

Comment: Even if there was jamb trim I'd still just drill it.  You can fill holes in trim not like the jamb is going to be stain grade.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Yes, the garage door opening is already trimmed, and siding is already up too.  Looking like I'll just have to drill through it all (including the trim, and fill the hole).  Was hoping I was just missing something in clear sight, but it is what it is.  Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

why not just go up through the top plate and then back down again.  Just make sure to fire caulk the holes in the top plate before inspection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately there's a 10" LVL beam that I can't drill through.  I ended up drilling from the side and was able to get it through.  Thanks!